# Assigning a logical name to a sql instance

Tags: sql-server, instance

How can we assign a logical name to a sql instance please? We would need to as to property identify messages coming through from the server.

**Update**

Thanks much for your replies. Yes it is for the instance name. Is it possible to assign one once the installation is already done? We now have two instances in this box, the other is server_name\inst2008. And it is the first instance that we want to name properly - which is now "local". I've considered Alias but I want to know another option - if there is. This instance is a SQL 2000 by the way.

Sorry just to clarify this topic... 
We have a server that for some reasons doesn't have a logical name - it doesn't have an entry in the sys.servers table for the local server (server_id = 0).

With some research and testing I was able to do this using sp_dropserver and sp_addserver commands.

Answer (score 2):

What I can think of is a server `alias`.

In SQL Server Configuration Manager, expand SQL Native Client Configuration, right-click Aliases, and then click New Alias.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean an instance name?  Instance names are assigned when SQL Server is installed.  If this isn't an answer please be more specific as to what you are trying to do.